# Not able to hide a div on a button click using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have 4 divs and 4 different buttons and i want to hide a particular div when its corresponding button is pressed.

my asp code is

```
<div class="div2">
    <div class="d1" id="one">
        <h3 class="h3">First Division</h3>
        <hr color="black" />
    <p class="text-green">
        //some text

    </p>
        <br />
        <asp:Button class="btn" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me to Hide" />
    </div>
    <div class="d1" id="two">
        <h3 class="h3">Second Division</h3>
        <hr color="black" />
    <p class="text-red" >
        //some text
    </p>
        <br />
        <asp:Button class="btn" ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Click Me to Hide" />
    </div>
    <div class="d1" id="three">
        <h3 class="h3">Thrid Division</h3>
        <hr color="black" />
    <p class="text-blue">
        //some text
    </p>
        <br />
        <asp:Button class="btn" ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Click Me to Hide" />
    </div>
    <div class="d1" id="four">
        <h3 class="h3">Fourth Division</h3>
        <hr color="black" />
    <p class="text-yellow">
        //some text
    </p>
        <br />
        <asp:Button class="btn" ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Click Me to Hide" />
    </div>
```

and my js code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Button1").click(function () {
    $("#one").hide('slow');
});
$("#Button2").click(function () {
    $("#two").hide('slow');
});
$("#Button3").click(function () {
    $("#three").hide('slow');
});
$("#Button4").click(function () {
    $("#four").hide('slow');
});
});
```

But nothing is happening on button clicks. What is the reason of such error??

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ClientIDMode="Static" to your asp:button, something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Button" />
```

This will make the ID remain the same. It disables the autogenerated names for this control.

Here is the reference for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx

Working Fiddle..have a look on below link it is working Fine
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7n5sR/)

Answer (score 0):

make sure to put e.preventDefault() in each error handler. for example

```
$("#Button1").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#one").hide('slow');
});
```

if you don't do this, it will cause an asp.net postback as these buttons are inside the form tag. and like another user said, remove runat="server", as this can change your id's.

you don't even need asp:button for this, you can just use html.

```
<button id="#Button1">Button Label</button>
```

Comment: and like another user said, remove runat="server",... what if needs to have some postbacks?

Comment: he doesn't need postbacks for what he's doing. he's just showing a div. if he does need a postback, he does need the runat="server" attribute.

Comment: asking him to Remove runat=server will take him to another conclusion instead you should have asked him to add ClientIDMode="Static"

Comment: why would he need his buttons to run on the server if he isn't going to bind them to a codebehind event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your JQuery to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.d1').hide('slow');
    });
});
```